# Importing issues to OJS (using XML Plugin) - where to place keywords, references and DOIs?

Tags: xml, ojs

I try to import old issues of my university journal to OJS, using XML plugin. I built xml issue files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE issue PUBLIC "-//PKP//OJS Articles and Issues XML//EN" "http://pkp.sfu.ca/ojs/dtds/native.dtd">

<issue published="false" current="false">
<title>August 2008, Volume 3, Number A08</title>
<volume>3</volume>
<number>A08</number>
<year>2008</year>

<section>
<title locale="en_US">Articles</title>
<abbrev locale="en_US">ART</abbrev>


<article>
<title>Approximating Counterparts</title>
<abstract>Abstract text...</abstract>
<pages>1-11</pages>
<date_published>2008-08-01</date_published>
<author primary_contact="true">
<firstname>FISTNAME</firstname>
<middlename><![CDATA[ ]]></middlename>
<lastname>LASTNAME</lastname>
<email>email@email</email>
</author>
<galley>
<label>PDF</label>
<file><href mime_type="application/pdf" src="http://...../issue/some.pdf"/></file>
</galley>
</article>


</section>
</issue>
```

And successfully imported them to OJS. However, I have a problem with keywords, DOIs and references. I don't know where to place them in my `sample.xml` file. Tags like `<keywords>...</keywords>` or `<references>...</references>` or `<doi>...</doi>` seem not to work, I mean they have no effect when I place them in my  `sample.xml` file.

Any ideas how to solve it?

I've already checked the examples in `/var/www/html/ojs/plugins/importexport/native`, searched `native.dtd` file but can't find the solution...

Answer (score 1):

The best documentation for import/export is: http://pkp.sfu.ca/wiki/index.php/Importing_and_Exporting_Data

Beyond that, to see what elements can be used, have a look at plugins/importexport/native/native.dtd. Alternately, you could also try exporting an article with the data you want to locate and see where it places it.

For keywords, use the <subject> element, e.g.:

```
<subject locale="en_US">mathematics, formal logic</subject>
```

For DOIs, use the <id> element, making sure to specify the type, e.g.:

```
<id type="doi">10.1234/t.v1i1.1-imp-test</id>
```

Citation import currently isn't supported using the native import/export plugin.